# getting error AttributeError: module 'urllib3.util.connection' has no attribute 'create_connection'. Did you mean: 'qcreate_connection'?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

`

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\Ryzen\python\xxxxx\xxxx.py", line 14, in 
> resp =requests.get(url)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 73, in get
> return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 59, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 589, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 703, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 486, in send
> resp = conn.urlopen(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 703, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 386, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)   File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 1042, in _validate_conn
> conn.connect()   File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 363, in connect
> self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 174, in _new_conn
> conn = connection.create_connection(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: module 'urllib3.util.connection' has no attribute 'create_connection'. Did
> you mean: 'qcreate_connection'?
>
> resp =requests.get(url)
> `

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.